# How to display "\s" as string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to transform `" - "` string in Ruby to being translatable to regexp. I need to have something like that:

```
my_regexp => "\s?-\s?"
```

However, I have a problem with **special characters**: This "\s" character isn't shown correctly. I tried few ways. Without success.

```
INPUT => OUTPUT
"\s?" => " ?"
"\\s?" => "\\s?"
```

Have you any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Do you want to match `\s` as a string? Or are you trying to match spaces?

Comment: Single quotes can also cut down on how much escaping is required: `'\s'` vs. `"\\s"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\` is just a escaped `\`.

If you `print`, `puts` it, you will see the actual string.

```
>> '\s'  # == "\\s"
=> "\\s"
>> puts '\s'
\s
=> nil
```

BTW, `"\s"` (not `'\s'`) is another representation of whitespace `" "`:

```
>> "\s" == " "
=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, what you're seeing is the result of how IRB displays values. Your second example is correct, (the actual result only contains a single slash, which you can confirm by creating a new Regexp object from it):

```
>> "\\s?"
"\\s?"
>> puts "\\s?"
\s?
>> Regexp.new "\\s?"
/\s?/
```